# Camel error handling fixed redelivery delay for azure storage queue not working correctly

Tags: azure, apache-camel

I have an azure app service that reads from a azure storage queue through camel route version **3.14.0**. Below is my code:

queue code:

```
QueueServiceClient client = new QueueServiceClientBuilder()
        .connectionString(storageAccountConnectionString)
        .buildClient();

getContext().getRegistry().bind("client", client);

    errorHandler(deadLetterChannel(SEND_TO_POISON_QUEUE)
    .useOriginalBody()
    .log("Message sent to poison queue for handling")
    .retryWhile(method(new RetryRuleset(), "shouldRetry"))
    .maximumRedeliveries(24)
    .asyncDelayedRedelivery()
    .redeliveryDelay(3600 * 1000L) // initial delay
    );

    // Route to retrieve a message from storage queue.
    from("azure-storage-queue:" + storageAccountName + "/" + QUEUE_NAME + "?serviceClient=#client&maxMessages=1&visibilityTimeout=P2D")
    .id(QUEUE_ROUTE_CONSUMER)
    .log("Message received from queue with messageId: ${headers.CamelAzureStorageQueueMessageId} and ${headers.CamelAzureStorageQueueInsertionTime} in UTC")
    .bean(cliFacilityService, "processMessage(${body}, ${headers.CamelAzureStorageQueueInsertionTime})")
    .end();
```

RetryRuleset code:

```
public boolean shouldRetry(@Header(QueueConstants.MESSAGE_ID) String messageId,
                           @Header(Exchange.REDELIVERY_COUNTER) Integer counter,
                           @Header(QueueConstants.INSERTION_TIME) OffsetDateTime insertionTime) {
    OffsetDateTime futureRetryOffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()).plusHours(1); //because redelivery delay is 1hr
    OffsetDateTime insertionTimePlus24hrs = insertionTime.plusHours(24);
    if (futureRetryOffsetDateTime.isAfter(insertionTimePlus24hrs)) {
        log.info("Facility queue message: {} done retrying because next time to retry {}. Redelivery count: {}, enqueue time: {}",
                messageId, futureRetryOffsetDateTime, counter, insertionTime);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

the redeliveryDelay is 1hr and maximumRedeliveries is 24, because i want to try once an hour for about 24 hrs. so not necessarily needs to be 24 times, just as many as it can do with 24hrs. and if it passes 24hrs, send it to the poison queue (this code is in the retry ruleset)

The problem is the app service retrying for first lets say 2 - 5 times normally once an hour. but after that the app service retries after 2 days later. So the message is expired and not retried because of the ruleset and sent to poison queue. Sometimes the app service does the first read from queue and the next retry is after 2 days. so very unstable. so total it is retrying tops 1-10 times and the last retry is **always** 2 days later in the same time from the first retry.

Is there anything i am doing wrong?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Can you please report the Camel version used?

Comment: 3.14.0. updated in the question as well.

Comment: happening with camel 3.20.1 as well